# My locomotions are unusual. What am I?

Tags: riddle

I swim on the soil.
I walk on the water.
I fly under the ground.
I sit on the air.

What am I?

Comment: A mole, Jesus, a bat, and a feather. Next! ;-)

Comment: For I am Chuck Norris

Comment: You are the God, sir. You are the omnipotent, with all respect.

Comment: It's been a while ... any chance of a hint?

Comment: @randal'thor Nope... :)

Comment: "Nope" is a funny-looking hint. Maybe N swims on the soil, O walks on the water, P flies under the ground, and E sits on the air? ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor Yeah, you got it.

Answer (score 5):

The locomotion bit made me think it would need to be a living thing, but I've decided to go a different way.

> Oil

It swims through the soil as a liquid, it doesn't mix with water, yet walks on its top.

When under ground it is under extreme pressure and can burst (fly) through the ground or become natural gas. It sits on the air because natural gas is lighter than air.

Comment: crude oil would be more precise :)

Answer (score 4):

> Water

I swim on the soil.

> A water find its way through the soil by swimming.

I walk on the water.

> Not sure. Iceberg

I fly under ground.

> steam formed due to heat under-ground. (Wild guess)

I sit on the air

> vapour

Explanations are a little hazy. Will try to add more base to it :)

Comment: I prefer palindromes.  Not sure which one I like better.  999 or 1001 :)  edit: except it would go to 1010...

Comment: Because leading zeros are valid, you could just express it as 01010. ;)

Comment: Interesting. :)

Answer (score 0):

I swim on the soil.

> a duck claps his wings when running on the ground giving the idea of a swimming motion.

I walk on the water.

> his feet make a walking motion when in the water.

I fly under the ground.

> well obviously a duck can fly, caves are under the ground, so technically they can fly underground.

I sit on the air.

> he could be gliding down, which granted isn't quite sitting but you could interpret it that way if you really want.

Comment: Fly **under the ground** - maybe you misread that?

Comment: @Raystafarian as in a cave? yeh i just bended it to what i needed xD

Comment: You should explain that in your answer

Comment: Ducks don't have wings long enough to glide. Any gliding action that they take is during their descent and is more of a controlled fall than a glide.